# select query return null when where cause has value with special character and comma

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

a column in a table has value of format lastName,firstname. some lastNames have special characters. for instance,

```
Full_Name
Gössel,Robert
Ocaña,Jack.
```

a select query

```
select * 
  from tblx 
 where fullname = 'Gössel,Robert';
```

is returning null.

How to handle special characters in database? I am using oracle 11g.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80306/1 What is the data type and character set for Full_Name?

Comment: I suspect that it is a COLLATE issue: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/COLLATE-Operator.html#GUID-1B8CE3B0-77FC-455C-8400-6F81CF188D7B

Comment: Is the column data type `varchar2` or `nvarchar2`? The second one natively supports unicode characters. The first one... well it's complicated.

Comment: I passed Gössel in from JSP and it gets converted to  G&auml ssel